# postgresql one to many as json result, how to filter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple db structure with a one to many relationship

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id                              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  email                           TEXT,
  first_name                      TEXT,
  last_name                       TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE customer_address (
  id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id     INTEGER                NOT NULL,
  street_name     TEXT                   NOT NULL,
  street_number   TEXT                   NOT NULL,
  zip_code        TEXT                   NOT NULL,
  city            TEXT                   NOT NULL
);
```

For my application I want to return each customer with all its addresses as one row, whereby I encapsulate all the addresses in a json array. This is done like this:

```
SELECT customer.*, 
       addresses 
FROM   customer 
       left join (SELECT 
Array_to_json(Array_agg( 
Json_build_object('id', address.id, 'street_name', address.street_name, 'street_number', address.street_number, 'zip_code', address.zip_code, 'city', address.city))) AS addresses,
address.customer_id 
AS customer_id 
 FROM   customer_address AS address 
 GROUP  BY address.customer_id) addresses 
       ON addresses.customer_id = customer.id 
join customer_address 
  ON customer_address.customer_id = customer.id
```

This works fine and gives me a resultset with for each result an element called `addresses` containing a JSON array of all the customer's addresses.

Now I would like to select all customers (with  all of their addresses) whose `street_name` is like a certain search term. And I can't get it to work. How can I select full records including all addresses inlined when one address has a street name containing a certain value (matched with an `ILIKE`) ?

I tried adding: `WHERE customer_address.street_name LIKE 'Ro'`, and while this works, if I replace this where statement with something completely different such as `WHERE customer.id > 0` I get doubles in the result set

Here is an sql Fiddle to play around in:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0e818/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This join condition looks wrong:

```
JOIN customer_address ON customer_address.id = customer.id
```

Shouldn't it be

```
JOIN customer_address ON customer_address.customer_id = customer.id
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fff0/6

Following the discussions on the original answer, here is the final solution that addresses the raised issues:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fff0/25

Comment: Well it sort of works it seems. It is indeed correct, but now if I run the query without the where clause it gives me double records

Comment: it would do that even if you have a where clause if that will return more than 1 addresses. At the same time, the last join is not needed if you don't have a where clause.

Comment: here is the updated fiddle that works with and without WHERE clause http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fff0/25

Comment: Nice! Could you post it in a separate reply or edit this one so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Does this cover your expected result?

> ```
> SELECT customer.*,addresses
> FROM customer 
> LEFT JOIN  (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('id',address.id,'street_name',address.street_name,'street_number',address.street_number,'zip_code',address.zip_code,'city',address.city))) AS addresses,address.customer_id AS customer_id 
>             FROM customer_address AS address 
>             GROUP BY address.customer_id) addresses 
> ON addresses.customer_id = customer.id    
> JOIN customer_address ON customer_address.id = customer.id
> WHERE customer_address.street_name LIKE 'Ro%'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | email         | first_name | last_name | addresses                                                                                                                                                                                       
> -: | :------------ | :--------- | :-------- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | john@test.com | John       | Doe       | [{"id" : 1, "street_name" : "Route", "street_number" : "222", "zip_code" : "9000", "city" : "NY"},{"id" : 2, "street_name" : "Ro", "street_number" : "444", "zip_code" : "9000", "city" : "LA"}]
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fb2a322f69293e7c349574b849b28f1c)*

Comment: Also see my edits above. This breaks down when replacing the WHERE with something generic such as 'customer.id > 0'. It gives double results